# How do I find files then gzip with a prefix date

Tags: linux, find, gzip

It's easy enough to do it with tar:

```
 date=`date +%F-%T`;find /var/log/nginx -name "access.log" -mtime -1 -type f -print | xargs -0 tar czvf /tmp/$date-access.tar.gz
```

.

```
$ ls /tmp
2019-05-03-11:25:49-access.tar.gz
```

How do I do this with gzip?

Answer (score 2):

`find` + `bash` + `gzip` solution:

```
$ d=$(date +%F-%T)
$ find /var/log/nginx -name "access.log" -mtime -1 -type f \
-exec bash -c 'gzip -c "$2" > "/tmp/$1-access.gz"' _ $d {} \;
```

Comment: I ran the command on a couple servers and it appears it doesn't do anything. Running a `locate` for todays date doesn't produce any files.